# Android RatingBar behaving wierdly

Tags: android

I'm scouring the Internet for a solution, but to no avail.

Here's two versions of XML for my RatingBar:

1)

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="4"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="2.0" />
```

2)

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="4"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="2.0" />
```

The difference is the first one has a style attribute. The bigger more problematic difference is setOnRatingBarChangeListener is working on the second one and not the first, and hence I'm unable to change the Rating in the first case. I need it to work on the first one, because the first one looks cooler.

What am I missing here? I'll probably kill myself if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the solution. Apparently android does not support user interaction on the prettier RatingBars.

The smaller RatingBar style ( ratingBarStyleSmall) and the larger indicator-only style (ratingBarStyleIndicator) do not support user interaction and should only be used as indicators.